# risk_score result for each of month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to generate highest risk_score result for each of month (Jan, Feb & Mar)
Displaying the following columns: Firm_id_1, risk_score_Jan, risk_score_Feb, risk_score_Mar

```
CREATE table firm_risk (
    firm_id_1 INT,
    assessment_date DATE,
    risk_score FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO firm_risk (firm_id_1, assessment_date, risk_score)
VALUES (123, '1/01/2018', 0.43),
        (123, '1/28/2018', 0.80),
        (123, '2/11/2018', 0.28),
        (123, '2/23/2018', 0.91),
        (123, '3/11/2018', 0.08),
        (123, '3/31/2018', 0.60),
        (456, '1/4/2018', 0.87),
        (456, '1/6/2018', 0.02),
        (456, '1/20/2018', 0.39),
        (456, '2/3/2018', 0.10),
        (456, '3/1/2018', 0.12),
        (789, '1/1/2018', 0.20),
        (789, '3/1/2018', 0.17);

SELECT * FROM firm_risk;

SELECT firm_id_1, date_part('month', assessment_date) AS AD
FROM firm_risk
WHERE assessment_date = (SELECT MAX (assessment_date) FROM firm_risk)
GROUP BY firm_id_1, risk_score, assessment_date;

CREATE table latest_risk_score (
  firm_id_2 integer,
  latest_risk_score_Jan float,
  latest_risk_score_Feb float,
  latest_risk_score_Mar float
);

SELECT * FROM latest_risk_score;

INSERT INTO latest_risk_score (firm_id_2) 
VALUES (123),
        (456),
        (789);

SELECT firm_risk.firm_id_1, date_part('month', assessment_date), firm_risk.risk_score
FROM firm_risk
INNER JOIN latest_risk_score
ON firm_risk.firm_id_1 = latest_risk_score.firm_id_2
GROUP BY firm_risk.firm_id_1, firm_risk.risk_score, assessment_date;

SELECT firm_risk.firm_id_1, date_part('month', assessment_date), firm_risk.risk_score
FROM firm_risk
WHERE assessment_date = (SELECT MAX (assessment_date) FROM firm_risk)
AND assessment_date LIKE '_%-01-2018%';

SELECT firm_risk.firm_id_1, date_part('month', assessment_date)
FROM firm_risk
WHERE assessment_date >= date_part('month', assessment_date - '3 months')
GROUP BY firm_risk.firm_id_1, ('month', assessment_date);

UPDATE latest_risk_score SET latest_risk_score_Jan = (SELECT Risk_Score FROM firm_risk.firm_id_1 WHERE Assessment_Date = (SELECT MAX(Assessment_Date) 
FROM firm_risk.firm_id_1 WHERE firm_id_1 = 123 AND Assessment_Date LIKE "2018-01-%" ORDER BY Assessment_Date)) 
WHERE firm_id_1 = 123; 


update latest_risk_score 
set latest_risk_score_Feb = (select Risk_Score from firm_risk.firm_id_1 where Assessment_Date = (select max(Assessment_Date) 
from firm_risk.firm_id_1 where firm_id_1 = 123 and Assessment_Date like "2018-02-%" order by Assessment_Date)) 
where firm_id_1 = 123; 

update latest_risk_score 
set latest_risk_score_Mar = (select Risk_Score from firm_risk.firm_id_1 where Assessment_Date = (select max(Assessment_Date) 
from firm_risk.firm_id_1 where firm_id_1 = 123 and Assessment_Date like "2018-03-%" order by Assessment_Date)) 
where firm_id_1 = 123; 

select * from latest_risk_score;
```

Comment: Please do not spam the tag. Tag only the database that you are using. Also include your current query and expected result

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE firm_risk;` and `SELECT version();`. Then post both results [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71246972/edit).

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags... feel free to add the correct one back.

Comment: I edited the question by pasting the query

Comment: I found similar question online with solution but it doesnt work me, most especially the last 4 query paragraphs

Comment: `date_part('month',` indicates you are using postgres, as I didn't see your initial tags would you add a tag to indicate the dbms you are using please - this matters because syntax changes by dbms

Comment: I tried doing but i dont know how to, im new here. I will appreciate if you can walk me through the process. Thanks

Comment: @dreh84 , can you just run `SELECT version();` and post the result here?

Comment: @FanoFN
"PostgreSQL 12.10, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit" this is the result

Comment: Great, thanks for the confirmation. Now that we know your RDBMS, looks like [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71247767/10910692) posted by @PaulMaxwell is spot on. Have you tried that suggestion?

Comment: the answer is on point. thanks you all for coming to my aid.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming postgres is relevant (due to existence of "date_part" in question)

> ```
> CREATE table firm_risk (
>     firm_id_1 INT,
>     assessment_date DATE,
>     risk_score FLOAT
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO firm_risk (firm_id_1, assessment_date, risk_score)
> VALUES (123, '2018-01-01', 0.43),
>         (123, '2018-01-28', 0.80),
>         (123, '2018-02-11', 0.28),
>         (123, '2018-02-23', 0.91),
>         (123, '2018-03-11', 0.08),
>         (123, '2018-03-31', 0.60),
>         (456, '2018-01-04', 0.87),
>         (456, '2018-01-06', 0.02),
>         (456, '2018-01-20', 0.39),
>         (456, '2018-02-03', 0.10),
>         (456, '2018-03-01', 0.12),
>         (789, '2018-01-01', 0.20),
>         (789, '2018-03-01', 0.17);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>       firm_risk.firm_id_1
>     , max(case when date_part('month',assessment_date) = 1 then firm_risk.risk_score end) jan_risk
>     , max(case when date_part('month',assessment_date) = 2 then firm_risk.risk_score end) feb_risk
>     , max(case when date_part('month',assessment_date) = 3 then firm_risk.risk_score end) mar_risk
> FROM firm_risk
> WHERE date_part('month',assessment_date) in (1,2,3)
> GROUP BY
>       firm_risk.firm_id_1
> ```

> ```
> firm_id_1 | jan_risk | feb_risk | mar_risk
> --------: | :------- | :------- | :-------
>       789 | 0.2      | null     | 0.17    
>       456 | 0.87     | 0.1      | 0.12    
>       123 | 0.8      | 0.91     | 0.6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ba43ce3925179ff61c6ce1cd25d921d9)*